# Timestamp based sorted data structure with logarithmic read complexity

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I'm looking for a good sorted data structure in java. After doing some research got few hints about using TreeSet/TreeMap. But these components is lack of one thing: random access to an element in the set. For example, I want to access nth element in the sorted set, but with TreeSet, I must iterate over other n-1 elements before I can get there. It would be a waste since I would have upto several thousands elements in my Set.

The use case is like below

```
9:20 AM what is this object? edited by user1
9:30 AM what is this book ? edited by user2
9:40 PM what is this red book? edited by user1
```

I always want to show the latest edited title by that user. I know that the latest is going to be with greatest timestamp. For this i found that `ConcurrentSkipListSet/Maps` are good. But, I would like to know if there are any better ways to implement this functionality.

Comment: In a balanced tree, you would only need to iterate over log N entries, not N-1 entries.

Comment: Why not just remember the latest element in a variable? Why do you need a collection?

Comment: I don´t understand. TreeSet and TreeMap are specifically build for random access to an element via the get() method.

Comment: @kan The reason is if the users revokes the edit i would like to get the previous version of the edited string.

Comment: To pick previous element form TreeSet you should not get element by index, but use NavigableSet methods to find element before.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you should keep your data sorted, your best bet is `TreeMap`. There's no silver bullet which is a sorted collection and also perform `O(1)` random access. In an ordered collection, you're capable of accessing an element with index directly but you cannot benefit from index based access if your collection is required sorted.

If you need concurrency, `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is good. It's suitable for large-scale concurrent access to data. However, in terms of performance, it's no match for our Red-Black tree based pal, `TreeMap`. Thus if you don't need concurrency, forget `ConcurrentSkipListMap` and stick with `TreeMap`.

`TreeMap` is elegant and satisfies your need. Nonetheless, in practice, using `HashMap` and sorting data whenever you need might be better. Try both and find out which one is better in your case.